# How can I exclude parameter from the format expression when option is null?

Tags: java, formatter

Here is my java code

```
System.out.format("a: %s b: %s c: %s", s1, s2, s3);
```

If `s2` is null, I want to print `a: <val> c: <val>` without `b: null`. If `s3` or any other param is null I want to skip it as well.

Seams that it should be some tricky expression.

*UPDATE*

Without `if/else` logic! Only using expressions inside of `format` method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems easier to break this into three calls

```
System.out.format("a: %s", s1);
if (s != null)
    System.out.format(" b: %s", s2);
System.out.format(" c: %s", s3);
```

If you absolutely wanted to put this into a single call, something like

```
System.out.format("a: %s%s%s c: %s", s1,
    (s2==null)?"":" b: ",
    (s2==null)?"":s2,
    s3);
```

could also work.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on a one-liner here is a possibility:

```
    System.out.format(
            (( s1 == null ? "" : "a: %1$s" )
            + ( s2 == null ? "" : " b: %2$s" )
            + ( s3 == null ? "" : " c: %3$s" )).trim(),
            s1, s2, s3
    );
```

(Yeah, not technically a one-liner, but one statement).

The idea: build the format string based on whether or not a given string is null. The `trim()` is there to get rid of the initial space before `b:` or `c:` in case `s1` was null.

Comment: It looks like s1 will be there unconditionally; only s2 and s3 could be null. You can get rid of the trim and the first conditional where you check s1 for null.